# Android Package Manager - verifyPendingInstall

Tags: android, package-managers, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

In Ice Cream Sandwich I see a new function for package manager which is

verifyPendingInstall()

"Allows a package listening to the package verification broadcast to respond to the package manager. The response must include the verificationCode which is one of VERIFICATION_ALLOW or VERIFICATION_REJECT."

http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/14/changes.html

I am curious to know its meaning as it is not very clear to me what exact difference it is trying to do here that was not done previously and what purpose it will achieve.

Any ideas?

EDIT: No thoughts by anyone?

Comment: Anybody up for some discussion?

Answer (score 0):

SO may not be the best place for discussions. Post on the official Android mailing lists, maybe someone will be able to shed some light.

If it is undocumented, your best bet is to check the source code. From a cursory look, it seems to be part of some kind of framework to allow multiple packages/process to allow or reject a package. Probably not useful for user-facing applications.